# MediaPlayer Android

Tags: android, media-player

I want to use MediaPlayer android, using this code, but I get an error, there's a way to fix this code, or can anyone bring me a better example for this?

```
try {

    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.setDataSource("/LFP/res/raw/Allen.mp3");
    player.prepare();
    player.start();

} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Tell us what you are getting in Logcat and we can provide help on that error.

Comment: Without a logcat it'll be difficult to help, but I'm assuming this is your issue: "/LFP/res/raw/Allen.mp3"

Comment: there say! "start called in state 2"

Comment: why do you use setDataSource if your mp3 is not a web address. if the mp3 file is in your raw file you should use MediaPlayer.create

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;

import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;

public class AudioPlayer extends Activity implements OnPreparedListener,                
MediaController.MediaPlayerControl{
private static final String TAG = "AudioPlayer";

public static final String AUDIO_FILE_NAME = "audioFileName";

private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private MediaController mediaController;
private String audioFile;

private Handler handler = new Handler();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.audio_player);

audioFile = this.getIntent().getStringExtra(AUDIO_FILE_NAME);
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.now_playing_text)).setText(audioFile);

mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);

mediaController = new MediaController(this);

try {
  mediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioFile);
  mediaPlayer.prepare();
  mediaPlayer.start();
} catch (IOException e) {
  Log.e(TAG, "Could not open file " + audioFile + " for playback.", e);
}

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
super.onStop();
mediaController.hide();
mediaPlayer.stop();
mediaPlayer.release();
}

  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

  mediaController.show();
  return false;
}

public void start() {
mediaPlayer.start();
}

public void pause() {
mediaPlayer.pause();
}

public int getDuration() {
return mediaPlayer.getDuration();
}

public int getCurrentPosition() {
return mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
}

public void seekTo(int i) {
mediaPlayer.seekTo(i);
}

public boolean isPlaying() {
return mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
}

public int getBufferPercentage() {
return 0;
}

public boolean canPause() {
return true;
}

public boolean canSeekBackward() {
return true;
}

public boolean canSeekForward() {
return true;
}

  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
  Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared");
  mediaController.setMediaPlayer(this);
  mediaController.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.main_audio_view));

   handler.post(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
     mediaController.setEnabled(true);
     mediaController.show();
     }
   });
  }
 }
```

This worked fine for me.Hope it works for you also.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
mediaplayer.prepareAsync() 
and 
mediaplayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.start();
                }
            });
```

instead it

Answer (score 0):

Here I am keeping my audio file in asset. Following code works,

```
MediaPlayer mp= new MediaPlayer();
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;
        try {
            afd =getActivity().getBaseContext().getAssets().openFd("myAudio.mp3");
            mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
            afd.close();
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();

            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.release();
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```